# Emoji icons pasted in emacs are shown as blank spaces

Tags: fonts

I have some emoji icons inserted in my shell terminal, which i am trying to copy and paste it into emacs
[image: emoji-shell]

When i copy the above text and paste it into my emacs window, it shows blank space in the place of emojis like,

```
echo I am not very happy  ;;<-- an extra space is visible at the line end instead of an angry face icon.
```

I use Mac OS El Capitan.

Comment: I don't think emoji characters are supported in GNU Emacs yet, generally. But I think maybe they are available for GNU Emacs on Mac OS. See [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2015-12/msg00713.html) in emacs-devel@gnu.org, as a starting point, perhaps.

Comment: @Drew It used to be able to, but the functionality was lost somewhere on the way to Emacs 25.  Iirc there's also a ticket for it, but I don't know what became of it.